# c# - unable to backup mysql database with error "The given path's format is not supported."

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, mysql-backup

```
private void Backup()
    {
        string x = txtb.Text; 
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        string file = x + date + "database backup.sql";
        string conn = "server = localhost; user id = root; password =; database = sais_db;";

        try
        {
            MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(conn);
            mb.Export(file);
            MessageBox.Show("Database Backup Success!");
        }

        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Help please, when I run my program, I get a `NotSupportedException` error. How do I fix it?

P.S. `txtb.Text` contains directory path like this C:\Users\user\Desktop

Comment: A colon is not acceptable in a filename on Windows. It's the drive separator character (as in `C:`). You cannot use `:` in the filename in the time portion. Use something else.

Comment: When I change `string file = x + date + "database backup.sql";` to `string file = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\database backup.sql";`, it works.

Comment: Yes, it works because you're properly using `:` as a drive separator. The issue is using it in other locations like the timestamp. `C:\Somefile.txt` is valid; `C:\Somefile:something.txt` is not. The colon is the **drive separator**; you can use it to indicate a drive letter, but you can't use it anywhere else in the filename.

Comment: Oh okay, it's working now, I just removed the time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your DateTime format includes colons. Those are not allowed in a file or pathname except for delimiting the drive letter from the path.

You can easily fix that by changing the format string of your DateTime.Now call:

```
string x = txtb.Text; 
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss");
string file = x + date + "database backup.sql";
```

When you run this you'll get (assumimg txtb.Text contains *foo*) in `file`

> foo09-24-2016 14-20-59database backup.sql

You can also consider to do that in one go:

```
string file = String.Format(
    "{0}{1:MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss}database backup.sql", 
    txtb.Text,
    DateTime.Now);
```

If you allow your users to provide (part of) a filename consider checking for invalid characters. The `Path` class in the System.IO namespace has a nice helper for that [`GetInvalidFileNameChars`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
if (file.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) > -1) 
{
    // show an error
    MessageBox.Show("invalid characters in file");
   return;
}
```

There is a similar method for InvalidPathChars